# SQL JOIN only in specific case

Tags: sql, codeigniter-4

I would like to - depending on the value of a column in table1 - either perform several joins or alternatively only display the contents of the main table1.

Unfortunately I don't get it. Here is my thought:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
CASE
 WHEN table1.more = 1
  THEN 
   LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.xyz= table2.xyz)
   LEFT JOIN table3 ON (table2.aaa= table3.aaa)
  ELSE
   END
WHERE
CASE
 WHEN table1.more = 1
  THEN table2.xyz = 12345
 ELSE
  table1.something = 1
```

Can someone help?

Comment: You need to study SQL a bit more.  Play with it, read books and try online examples.  This is just a case of not knowing enough about how the language fits together. @Parzival is probably correct, but until you understand the structure of the language his guidance may not be too helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into the **[`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)** keyword.
Something like:

```
CASE WHEN table1.more = 1
THEN ...
ELSE ...
END
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the CASE in my example. I corrected it accordingly. Would the syntax be allowed like that?

Comment: No - `CASE` cannot be used after the table name. You might want to consider joining the tables first, and then use the `CASE` to select the columns you needed

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.xyz= table2.xyz and table1.more = 1
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.aaa= table3.aaa and table1.more = 1
WHERE
 (case WHEN table1.more = 1  THEN 12345 else table2.xyz end )=table2.xyz
 and
 (case WHEN table1.more = 1  THEN 1 else table1.something end )= 1
```